# PayPal micropayment

Tags: paypal

I m planning to integrate micropayment in my ASP.NET website. I need to use PayPal to achieve this.

The cost of the service I deliver is low, about $1 per month. I'd like to know more about PayPal service for this kind of cheap transactions.

How much does PayPal hold for each $1 payment ? I found [this](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/merchant-fees) explaining the PayPal conditions for micropayment. Any feedback on this ?

Plus, how does PayPal handle currency conversion ? My service is worldwide, so I want my users to be able to buy my product not only using dollars, but euros or another currency.

Thanks

Comment: Not about programming, not suitable for Super User.

Answer (score 1):

In the link you quoted the fees section is expandable and you can see the Micropayments pricing:
5% + $0.05

Signing up for it doesn't require any vetting or contract changes. Contact Customer Service and they file a request to a team that enables Micropayments. Should be done within a few days.

Currency conversion and cross-border transacitons are also in this page:
International Sales: The pricing table above applies to domestic payments in US dollars. There's an additional 2.5% charge for any currency conversion and a 1% charge to receive payments from another country.

If you decide to charge your buyers in USD only, they will be able to choose if they wish he card issuer or PayPal to convert the money. Most won't even notice the conversion took place and it will make your reconciliation much easier.